# Does it make sense to consider God meaning is 0?

Tags: theology, existence-of-god

**Foreword:**
Mathematics is science, that can prove or disprove everything.
That is the meaning of Mathematics, prove or disprove any statement.
When somebody say something, that something are statements or propositions.
Those statements or propositions can be proved or disproved.
God meaning is very simple, because ancient people had something evident to see
that impressed them and can be shown with finger.
That something is Sky with stars and Interstellar Space, that is Nothing or Zero,
that is the foundation of The Universe and keeps all the celestial bodies, but ancient people named it: God.
Mathematically, God meaning is 0.

The meaning of 1 is The Body. God has body? Son has body? Holy Spirit has body?
That is why i am considering from Mathematical view God meaning is 0,
because God does not have body, to consider Him 1.
You are one 1, the body. I am one 1, the body.

---

**Dialog:**
— What is God meaning and how wide is Zero?
— God meaning is Zero and Zero is infinitely wide as wide as The Universe is
and Zero is The Interstellar Space that is the foundation of The Universe and keeps all The Celestial Bodies.

---

**Question:**
Does it make sense to consider God meaning is 0?

---

**Errata:**
To say directly as is: Religions are lies and untruth, God is lies and untruth, because Religions and God were invented by humans, that is why they are so many, therefore Sciences are like Religions and God. That is why so many interpretations trying to guess about God: what could be. God is not a person or body we can hit with stone. God meaning is 0, from my Mathematical point of view.

---

Comment: Mathematics gives you the freedom to abstract any thing with any meaning. An apple can be abstracted as 1. So, you can add apples. And maths it's not science (empirical truth), it's metaphysics (rational truth).

Comment: @RodolfoAP, Yes. The Apples is kind of body. We can count them. I am agree.

Comment: @RodolfoAP, Here I tried to express and link God meaning, Truth meaning and Absolute Knowledge: Defining God
https://chat.openai.com/share/24ef7fbc-4455-45ad-8f44-21944bd5104e

Comment: "Mathematics is science, that can prove or disprove everything." Everything? Certainly not. Including many perfectly meaningful mathematical statements (thanks to Gödel undecidability). But also, mathematics cannot prove anything outside the province of mathematics, like the existence of the universe.

Comment: @DanielAsimov, You are absolutely right. And do You know why is that? Because before all Sciences was and is Philosophy. That means that Philosophy is the Mother of all Sciences. You correct noted this important observation. Thank You.

Comment: 0 is a number, while God is God: different "definitions" according to different religions.

Comment: Mathematics **cannot** prove or disprove everything.

Comment: **Not** every statement or proposition can be proved or disproved.

Comment: Ancient people had something evident to see that impressed them and can be shown with finger. That something is Sky with stars and Interstellar Space, that is Nothing or Zero. We **cannot** "show with finger" neither Zero nor Interstellar Space.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, If so, we cannot know what is True, we cannot know what is False, we cannot know what is 1, we cannot know what is 0, we cannot know what is correct, we cannot know what is wrong. Because we cannot prove or disprove everything.

Comment: In conclusion, it does **not** make sense to consider God meaning as 0.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, if so, just You can tell me what is God and show him to me with finger. Can You? More than that, if You say "that is not that", that means You know what is "that is".

Comment: Maybe there is no God... and which case that is the reason why we cannot "show him with finger".  About "what is God", there are different purported definitions according to different religions.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, and when You say "no God" is like to say "no apples", resulting again meaning of zero 0.

Comment: To say directly as is: Religions are lies and untruth, God is lies and untruth, because Religions and God were invented by humans, that is why they are so many, therefore Sciences are like Religions and God. That is why so many interpretations trying to guess about God: what could be.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems

Comment: [Conclusion:](https://medium.com/@gvitalie/zero-is-odd-or-even-number-9472f489bf94) *Virgin Mary is The Nature as whole and entire Universe, where Jesus Christ is Logos expressing all meanings of Absolute Knowledge from The Universe.*

Answer (score 3):

To be brief and perhaps blunt: no, it does not.

Comment: Maybe. But this point of view help me to answer clearly what is what and how and when.

Comment: best of luck to you. I am going to bed now, good night.

Comment: Good night dear friend. Get a peaceful rest.

Answer (score 1):

To be splitting hairs, yep, it maketh a whole lotta sense. How exactly? Well, there be many kinds a meanings/definitions.

If we be looking at *intensional definitions*, we be saying God is omnibenevolent, omniscient, and omnipotent. We're basically listing down divine attributes.

From an *extensional definition* pointa view, mirrors *ostensive definitions*, the set Gods, G,  is the *empty set* {  }. We've, in our million or so years of existence, never encountered anything we could make a member of the set G. That is to say the number of elements/members of G is 0/zilch/nyx/nada, notationally n(G) = 0.

Ostensively, there's *nothing* (0) you can point to and announce, *(this here is) God!*.

I guess I'm saying God doesn't exist. No, I don't wanna say that!!